# How to select specific weeks in a datetime indexed dataframe and plot their mean

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm sorry my title may be a little bit confusing.

I got a huge datetime indexed dataframe with 1 entry per hour during 2 years.

I'm trying to study different seasonality at different scale (year, month, week, day...)

I had no problem to plot year, month, weeks or daily graphs, but I'm stuck for the next step.

I want to select a specific range of data (let's say for example between May and September if I want to study the summer), and plot a graphic representing the mean hour per hour of the selected period, on a week.
Like my first point would be the mean of all Mondays at 01:00 AM during this period, the second point the mean at 02:00, etc. till Sunday 23:00.

I just can't figure out how to do this, if someone can give me a clue :/

Hope you'll have all a nice day

Edit I don't have much code but I'll try to show you anyway.

I have tried to find one value, now I want to create a function that can find all the others and plot the graphic

```
season=df.loc['2019-04':'2019-09']
x=season[["column_name"]][(saison["hour"]==1)&(season["day"]==1)]
x.mean()
```

This give me the value i'm looking for for 1 AM, the monday.
Now I want to create a loop that can generate all the values in the right order to plot the whole week

Well, I Finally got my solution by using this

```
def graph(a,b,c): #With "a' the date starting the period I want, 'b' the date ending it and 'c' the column I want to plot
    saison=df.loc[a:b]
    test=[]
    for i in range (7):
        for j in range (24):
            x=season[[c]][(season["hour"]==j)&(season["day"]==i)]
            z=x.mean()
            test.append(z)
    plt.figure(figsize=[18,10])
    plt.xticks([0,24,48,72,96,120,144],['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'])
    plt.plot(test)
```

pretty sure it's not the sexiest way to do it, but it seems working enough for now :)

Comment: Please, add a minimal code to reproduce

Comment: I added a little bit of code to explain, but my problem si I don't find the way to start the code so I don't have much of it :/

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a way to do it, I edited the first post I hope it will help other peoples

Comment: Take a look to `seaborn`